# Insert statements more than values clause must match the number of columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> There are more columns in the `INSERT` statement than values specified in the `VALUES` clause. The number of values in the `VALUES` clause must match the number of columns specified in the `INSERT` statement.'

This is my code:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
                ms.Close();

                MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms1, pictureBox2.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] a2 = ms1.GetBuffer();
                ms1.Close();

                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox3.Image.Save(ms2, pictureBox3.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] a3 = ms2.GetBuffer();
                ms2.Close();

                MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox4.Image.Save(ms3, pictureBox4.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] a4 = ms3.GetBuffer();
                ms3.Close();


                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
               // cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

                cmd.Connection = con;
               cmd1.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", a);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img2", a2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img3", a3);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img4", a4);

             cmd1.CommandText = "Insert into proiecte(numeproiect,judet,oras,strada,numaretajeimobil,clasaenergetica,parcare,mezanin,demisol,mansarda,descriereproiect)values('"
+ nameofproject.Text + "','" + district_text.Text + "','" + city_text.Text + "','" + street_text.Text + "','" + bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "','" + bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue + "','" + mezanine + "','" + semibasement + "','" + mansard + richTextBox1.Text + "')";
               cmd.CommandText = "insert into proiecte(img1,img2,img3,img4)values(@img1,@img2,@img3,@img4)";
                con.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
}
```

Comment: How is that error message in any way confusing?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I would like to point out that your `cmd1` is subject to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) attacks and you really ought to look into fixing that.  It's interesting that you apparently know how to use parameterized queries because you are doing so in `cmd` - be sure to do the same for `cmd1`!

Comment: It is the same as if I wrote: `insert into sometable(column1) values(1,2,3,4,5)`. The sql server is saying: *Come on dude! Do you want me to insert 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5? You need to make sure the number of columns is the same as the number of values you are giving me. Dont give me 5 values and ask me to insert them into 1 column. Smarten up dude!*

Comment: You should take a look at the SQL statement produced by your code to make sure it's executable.  After you do that, I'm sure it will be very straightforward to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert command has 11 column with 10 values

```
    cmd1.CommandText = "Insert into proiecte(
                            numeproiect
                            ,judet
                            ,oras
                            ,strada
                            ,numaretajeimobil
                            ,clasaenergetica
                            ,parcare
                            ,mezanin
                            ,demisol
                            ,mansarda
                            ,descriereproiect)

                    values(
                            '"+ nameofproject.Text + "'
                            ,'" + district_text.Text + "'
                            ,'" + city_text.Text + "'
                            ,'" + street_text.Text + "'
                            ,'" + bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue + "'
                            ,'" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "'
                            ,'" + bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue + "'
                            ,'" + mezanine + "'
                            ,'" + semibasement + "'
                            ,'" + mansard + richTextBox1.Text + "')";
```

Update: for your comment, combine cmd1 and cmd by remove cmd1 and build cmd like that

```
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into proiecte(
                             numeproiect
                            ,judet
                            ,oras
                            ,strada
                            ,numaretajeimobil
                            ,clasaenergetica
                            ,parcare
                            ,mezanin
                            ,demisol
                            ,mansarda
                            ,descriereproiect
                            ,img1
                            ,img2
                            ,img3
                            ,img4)

                    values(@numeproiect
                            ,@judet
                            ,@oras
                            ,@strada
                            ,@numaretajeimobil
                            ,@clasaenergetica
                            ,@parcare
                            ,@mezanin
                            ,@demisol
                            ,@mansarda
                            ,@descriereproiect
                            ,@img1
                            ,@img2
                            ,@img3
                            ,@img4)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numeproiect", nameofproject.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judet", district_text.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oras", city_text.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strada", street_text.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clasaenergetica", bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parcare", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mezanin", mezanine );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demisol", semibasement );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mansarda", mansard);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriereproiect", a);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", a);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img2", a2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img3", a3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img4", a4);
```

Remember to fix error varbinary and correct parameter. I just copy paste it from your question so It contain error

Comment: Thanks, but now  it give's  me THIS :  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'

Comment: cmd or cmd1 cause that error ? And could you post your table structure ?

Comment: cmd1 is created by string combine so all of them has datatype varchar when it is sent to your db. Check your table structure and rebuild cmd1 with variable like cmd then correct your parameter

Comment: I resolved that error, in my table structure i had varbinary instead varchar but.. I would now like the two commands to be matched because he gives me cmd1 on one row and cmd on another row

Comment: Ok, thank you very much sir, i wish you all the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160041/discussion-between-khanh-bui-dc-and-iulian-glvan).

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though you have 11 columns in the INSERT part but only 10 values to enter.

You might need to add another comma between the **mansard + richTextBox1.Text** section.

Answer (score -2):

Your issue is with the last two VALUES

```
+ "','" + mansard + "', '" + richTextBox1.Text + "')";
```

This assumes both are text values. If not, just remove the single quotes, but you need the comma.